# Correct way to fill a list from a SQL query using pyodbc

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pyodbc

Is this the correct way to get a list from a SQL query in Python 2.7? Using a loop just seems somehow spurious. Is there a neater better way?

```
import numpy as np
import pyodbc as SQL
from datetime import datetime

con = SQL.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=MyServer; Database=MyDB; UID=MyUser; PWD=MyPassword')
cursor = con.cursor()

#Function to convert the unicode dates returned by SQL Server into Python datetime objects
ConvertToDate = lambda s:datetime.strptime(s,"%Y-%m-%d")

#Parameters
Code = 'GBPZAR'

date_query = '''
             SELECT DISTINCT TradeDate 
             FROM MTM 
             WHERE Code = ? 
               and TradeDate > '2009-04-08' 
             ORDER BY TradeDate
            '''

#Get a list of dates from SQL
cursor.execute(date_query, [Code])
rows = cursor.fetchall()
Dates = [None]*len(rows) #Initialize array
r = 0
for row in rows:
    Dates[r] = ConvertToDate(row[0])
    r += 1
```

**Edit:**

What about when I want to put a query into a structured array? At the moment I do something like this:

```
#Initialize the structured array
AllData = np.zeros(num_rows, dtype=[('TradeDate', datetime),
                                    ('Expiry', datetime), 
                                    ('Moneyness', float),
                                    ('Volatility', float)])

#Iterate through the record set using the cursor and populate the structure array
r = 0
for row in cursor.execute(single_date_and_expiry_query, [TradeDate, Code, Expiry]):
    AllData[r] = (ConvertToDate(row[0]), ConvertToDate(row[1])) + row[2:] #Convert th0e date columns and concatenate the numeric columns
    r += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to pre-create a list, you could use `list.append()` instead. This also avoids having to keep a counter to index into `Dates`.

I'd use a list comprehension here, looping *directly* over the cursor to fetch rows:

```
cursor.execute(date_query, [Code])
Dates = [datetime.strptime(r[0], "%Y-%m-%d") for r in cursor]
```

You may want to add `.date()` to the `datetime.strptime()` result to get `datetime.date` objects instead.

Iterating over the cursor is preferable as it avoids loading all rows as a list into memory, only to replace that list with another, processed list of dates. See the [`cursor.fetchall()` documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#fetchall):

> Since this reads all rows into memory, it should not be used if there are a lot of rows. Consider iterating over the rows instead.

To produce your `numpy.array`, don't prepopulate. Instead use [`numpy.asarray()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html#numpy.asarray) to turn the cursor items into an array, with the help of a generator:

```
dtype=[('TradeDate', datetime), ('Expiry', datetime), 
       ('Moneyness', float), ('Volatility', float)]
dt = lambda v: datetime.strptime(v, "%Y-%m-%d")
filtered_rows = ((dt(r[0]), dt(r[1]) + r[2:]) for r in cursor)
all_values = np.asarray(filtered_rows, dtype=dtype)
```

For future reference, you can use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to produce a counter with a loop:

```
for r, row in enumerate(rows):
    # r starts at 0 and counts along
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. If I then execute a second query just after that, the cursor will reset right?

Comment: Yes, the cursor will reset with every new `.execute()`.

Comment: Sorry, just added to the question. Please see my edit. Can I use list comprehension like that to get a structured array instead of a list?

Comment: That `enumerate()` idea looks pretty cool, so is that like getting an automatic counter in a for-each loop?

Comment: Yes, `enumerate()` provides an automatic counter.

Comment: For `numpy` arrays, I believe there is a `fromiter()` method to produce the array.

Comment: @Dan: added a numpy option for you.